# Do context diagrams have levels?

Tags: diagrams, data-flow-diagram

I heard that the context analysis diagram has different levels. I couldn't find this in .Net, but I have seen that a DFD has different levels.

Do context diagrams have any levels (`level0`, `level1`, `level2`)? If yes, please suggest some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends upon what type of Context Diagram you are referring to.

- [System Context Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_context_diagram) have a single layer only.  So the answer is "No".
  From the Wikipedia article:

> This diagram is the highest level view of a system.

- [IDEF0 Top Level Context Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0) have a single top-level context diagram and then have optional 'child' diagrams below that.  So the answer here would be "Yes."

> The IDEF0 process starts with the identification of the prime function to be decomposed. This function is identified on a “Top Level Context Diagram,” that defines the scope of the particular IDEF0 analysis. ... From this diagram lower-level diagrams are generated.